Issue with XML coloring using Piton package
Issue with XML coloring using Piton package.
There seems to be a line break error. See photo. How to fix?
MWE:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}
%========================================
\babelfont{rm}[Scale=0.976]{TimesNewRoman}
\babelfont{tt}[Scale=0.976]{CourierNew}
%========================================
\usepackage{piton}

\PitonOptions{
    line-numbers={
        skip-empty-lines=false,
        label-empty-lines=true,     
        format=\footnotesize\color{black}
    },
    break-lines,
    indent-broken-lines,
    detected-commands={highLight},
}

\usepackage{color}

\NewPitonLanguage{XML}
{ 
    morekeywords = { version , encoding , standalone , xmlns , type , version },    
    alsoother=$,
    alsoletter=:,   
    morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},
    tag=<>,
    morestring=[d]",
}

\SetPitonStyle[XML]
  {
    Tag = \color{blue},
    String = \color{black},    
    Keyword = \color{cyan},
    Comment = \color{orange},
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{Piton}[language=XML, line-numbers, auto-gobble]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- информация о сотруднике -->
<employee>
 <fio>
  <first_name>Иванова</first_name>
   <last_name>Валя</last_name>
   <second_name>Владимировна</second_name>
  </fio>
  <post>Старший лаборант лаборатории глобавльных исследований</post>
  <work_address>
   <postal-code>111024</postal-code>
   <city>Город</city>
   <street>Улица</street>
   <house_number>10-А</house_number>
   <email>xxxx@mmmm.com</email>
   <telephone code="7-495">XXX-XX-XX</telephone>
  </work_address>
</employee>
\end{Piton}
\end{document}



Use \shorthandoff{"} before the listing. Or disable the shorthand generally, see the babel documentation.
